# Bob dies because Eve chose not to be vaccinated, is this a crime?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom

Bob is a clinically vulnerable adult that has a weak immune system. Eve is one of Bob's friends. Eve has been offered a vaccine for a widely spread and contagious disease that has the potential to kill Bob if he caught it from Eve. Eve does not take this vaccine, as she does not think it will affect her and it goes against her beliefs/morals.

Unfortunately, Eve catches this disease and then passes it on (transmits) it to Bob. As a result, Bob becomes ill and dies. Could Eve be tried for murder, manslaughter, or some other crime, as she chose not to be vaccinated against a disease that she (in-directly) passed on to Bob and killed him?

Comment: How do you prove Bob caught the disease from Eve, rather than Carol who he stood next to in the supermarket or Dave who came round to fix the air conditioner?

Comment: @JamesPD Let's assume that Eve lives with Bob, and Bob does not leave his home often, while Eve does.

Comment: Does Eve know she is infected or is she asymptomatic?

Comment: Furthermore, is Eve aware that refusing the vaccine puts Bob in danger?

Comment: How do you prove, with the certitude required for a conviction, that Bob died of covid?  Tests can have false positives, and many other diseases have similar presentations.

Comment: @Ryan_L  I never said it would be Covid, it could be any infectious disease (flu, SARS, swine flu, etc.)

Comment: @AsheraH Eve is aware of this fact

Comment: @RockApe Eve was aware that she was infected

Comment: Dear God. Why does everyone want to fight with the question instead of answering it? The question is not about what evidence is required to sustain the conviction, but rather whether the facts would support a criminal charge.

Comment: @bdb484 This particular SE site is filled with lawyers and that's just their nature. It can be really annoying sometimes. However, I think they are trying to whittle it down for a better response. The more questions & answers you read here, the better you'll get at specifying the limits of each scenario. Overall good question!

Comment: @bdb484  If I am to arrest someone in connection with the suspicious death of another, and then refer the case to the CPS for a charging decision, I need to be sure (as far as I can be) that I have all the relevant facts. Although one can read between the lines, the Q does not have enough IMO to go on. However, the OP's replies to comments have added some of the absent details.

Comment: The case of Mary Mallon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Mallon otherwise known as Typhoid Mary could offer some insights...

Comment: A more serious and real case: https://arstechnica.com/health/2023/06/woman-with-untreated-tb-finally-in-custody-held-in-negative-pressure-room/ Woman with tuberculosis refusing to get treatment or to isolate is finally caught and arrested. Seems that meeting someone with active tuberculosis is more dangerous than Covid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> As a result, Bob becomes ill and dies. Could Eve be tried for Murder,
> Manslaughter, or some other crime, as she chose not to be vaccinated
> against a disease that she (in-directly) passed on to Bob and killed
> him?

There are basically two distinct issues here. What is the duty? And if a duty was breached, what intent is necessary to breach it?

There is not a legal duty to be vaccinated. There is a duty to use reasonable care not to hurt others. The duty not to hurt others could be satisfied by not seeing Bob in person, by wearing a mask around Bob or by having other non-transmission means available, in addition to being vaccinated. But Eve didn't do any of these things.

We don't know if Eve had any reason to think that she presented a risk of infection to Bob because she could have passed the virus to him while she was asymptomatic.

We also know, by the assumption of the question, that Eve was the source of the infection. But, in real life, proving the source of an infection beyond a reasonable doubt is very challenging or impossible. This must be established for any homicide crime.

There is no indication that Eve knew she was transmitting the virus to Bob, or that Eve intended to transmit the virus to Bob (if she intentionally spat in Bob's face intending to infect him that would be a different matter). At most, her conduct was reckless, but if she was asymptotic and has no idea that she was doing something that was actually putting Bob at risk, her intent could be as slight as negligent (for tort law purposes only) or criminally grossly negligent.

Since she lacked [the necessary intent to commit murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicide_in_English_law) (i.e. either an intention to kill, or an intention to inflict grievous bodily harm), she could not be guilty of the offense of murder.

There are three types of voluntary manslaughter in England, none of which apply here: "There are three types of voluntary manslaughter: that resulting from loss of self-control; that resulting from statutorily defined diminished responsibility; and killing in perseverance of a suicide pact."

So, this leaves involuntary manslaughter as the most serious possible homicide offense. Involuntary manslaughter could encompass either reckless conduct (i.e. "the unlawful act must be such that all sober and reasonable people would inevitably recognise it as an act which must subject the other person to at least the risk of some harm resulting therefrom albeit not serious harm") and is usually in furtherance of some other criminal offense, or in the case of "gross negligence manslaughter", negligent conduct that is a far greater level of wrongdoing than the negligence that would suffice for civil tort liability.

Gross negligence manslaughter is the most plausible charge and is itself a hard call that involves judgement and discretion on the part of the trier of fact (i.e. the judge in a bench trial, and the jury in a jury trial) that is exercised on a case by case basis considering all of the circumstances. Also, to be clear, the wrongful act in a gross negligence involuntary manslaughter case would be transmitting the virus (which could have been prevented multiple ways) and not failing to get vaccinated itself.

Comment: Back in the '80s and 90's in America there were cases of people with HIV/AIDS who deliberately sought out casual unprotected sex enounters in a spiteful way to infect others. It was back when HIV/AIDS was a death sentence, before viable treatments were available. I recall there were guilty convictions, but I don't remember if the charges were for murder or similar, or what the sentences were.

Comment: @KirkHings A big factor was the greater ease of proving the identity of the source of the infection (i.e. causation). Some statutes were later passed to squarely address the issue in some states, rather than relying on case law reasoning.

Comment: The pattern might shift if she was under a mandatory quarantaine/isolation order by the health authority. Some illnesses are so rare (think plague) that the mere occurrence of it in two places *and* establishing that there was contact is enough to prove infection source.

Comment: @Trish This would establish both a duty and make causation more clear.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of argumentation, let me use the law from [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) here.

Under the condition, that the illness is a tracked infection under §6 Infektionsschutzgesetz (law for the protection from infections), then they are legally obliged to isolate and enter quarantine. That means, the mere act of meeting Bob would be a violation of law. Among the illnesses on that list are Cholera, Yellow Fever, *Variola vera* and *Yersinia pestis* - smallpox and plague. But SARS-COV-2 is also on that list.

By *purposefully* meeting anyone **while being under the mandated quarantine or isolation**, Eve not only is to be fined for that (violating the quarantine) but also can be liable for damage to Bob as, according to the law, transmission is foreseeable. However, we can't *a priori* assume the necessary murder criteria in Germany, so it is possibly better described as Körperverletzung mit Todesfolge (StGB §227 - infliction of bodily harm resulting in death) or negligent homicide (StGB §222). The latter is punishable with up to 5 years or fine, the former with at least 3 years normally and 1 to 10 in lesser cases. However, there might be grounds for trying to go for other unlawful killing statutes, based on the exact pattern.

Comment: Even though it’s not the country the question was tagged for, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: @Spacefighter The main thing of the exercise with Germany was, that the treatment of Eve by law might rely on the interaction of public health laws and what those mandate and then violating those mandates. If you were ordered to isolate or put under quarantine, violating that puts you on notice that you are banned from seeing anyone - which then interacts with the laws on inflicting bodily harm or killing somebody.

Comment: 1-10 monthes or years in lesser cases?

Comment: Austria has a distinct statute for exactly this: § 178 StGB "Vorsätzliche Gefährdung von Menschen durch übertragbare Krankheiten" i.e. intentionally endangering people through communicable diseases.